# How to correctly access properties in a JSON from Python?

Tags: python, json, google-slides-api

EDIT: As pointed out by some users, the request does not actually returns a JSON, but a string encoded JSON.
The issue here is not actually parsing the JSON in python, but writing it in such a way that a request can be sent to the API. Therefore, it's not necessary to use the json python library.

I'm using the various google APIs (slides, drive, sheets and such) with a python program.
I am having issues accessing the properties in the JSON that the API requests return.

Take a slides [presentations().get](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/get?apix_params=%7B%22presentationId%22%3A%22%5C%221SbvctMvcyy4SgE7Bxg82bhkx5N9SlNGrwX9xFwLTuhQ%5C%22%22%7D) request for example.
It returns an [instance of presentation](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations).
And I want to access its Slides property, which is an array of [page objects](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations.pages).

So I am trying the code

```
slideInfo = SLIDES.presentations().get(presentationId=presId).execute()
slideInfo = slideInfo.get(['slides'][0]['pageType'])
```

But I get an error message saying "TypeError: string indices must be integers"

However, I thought that using brackets with a string was an acceptable replacement for accesing with a dot. In fact, I don't know how to translate this to dot accesors because it throws a syntax error since the keys have to be wrapped in quotes.

```
'slides'[0].'pageType'
```

throws syntax error because of the dot, and without the dot it doesnt work either

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So with the JSON representation in the docs:

```
{
  "presentationId": string,
  "pageSize": {
    object (Size)
  },
  "slides": [
    {
      object (Page)
    }
  ],
  "title": string,
  "masters": [
    {
      object (Page)
    }
  ],
  "layouts": [
    {
      object (Page)
    }
  ],
  "locale": string,
  "revisionId": string,
  "notesMaster": {
    object (Page)
  }
}
```

You can access the slides using: `slideInfo.get('slides')` or `slideInfo['slides']`

So if you want to get the `pageType` of the first slide, it would be:

```
slideInfo['slides'][0]['pageType']
```

or

```
slideInfo.get('slides')[0].get('pageType')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're actually getting a string back. JSON objects act exactly like dictionaries, by the way. You should use the json package to parse your result first. If you *are* actually getting a proper JSON result, you should access it like a dictionary

```py
import json

slideInfo = SLIDES.presentations().get(presentationId=presId).execute()

# parse the JSON object into a dict
slideInfo = json.parse(slideInfo)
# access the JSON object like a dict
slideInfo = slideInfo['slides'][0]['pageType']
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the request is returning a json encoded string. In that case, you have to load that into a dictionary using python's standard `json` library.

```py
import json

slideInfo = SLIDES.presentations().get(presentationId=presId).execute()
slideInfo = json.loads(slideInfo)
slideInfo = slideInfo.get('slides')[0]['pageType']
```